# Узнать количество элементов в ряде

Tags: css3, flexbox, less, media-queries

Имею адаптивные карточки объявлений на сайте *(смотреть на пикчере)*.
[image: первое]
Их количество и ширина зависят от экрана.
Для этого использую: `display: flex; flex-grow: 1;`
И сталую ширину `width: 245px;` относительно которой будут тянуться.
Пример смотреть здесь -> **[Адаптивные карточки](http://workout.korets.in.ua/xbolt/catalog.html)**

---

Задача состоит в том, что при уменьшении размеров, элементов в последующих рядах становиться недостаточно и они занимают всю ширину блока *(смотреть на пикчере)*.
[image: второе]
Где красным изображено, как оно тянется сейчас. Зеленым, как надо. Серым, пустое место для последующих карточек.
Использую: **flexbox, LESS и media query**.
Вопрос заключается в том: «Как узнать количество элементов в ряде со свойством flex-wrap: wrap?!»
Из чего пойдет решение через: `max-width: calc(100% / (количество элементов в ряде));`

---

**Поправка**
Интересует именно: "Как узнать количество элементов в ряде?"

Comment: Впринципе вполне отлично подойдет решение и через jQuery!

Comment: Интересует именно: "Как узнать количество элементов в ряде?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задание посредствами *jQuery*:

```js
function AdaptiveCards() {
    var rowWidth = $("row").width(); // ширина блока в котором лежат элементы
    var countItems = Math.floor(rowWidth / 260); // 245 - базовая ширина, относительно которой тянеться элемент + 15 маргины
    var itemWidth = Math.floor(rowWidth / countItems) - 15; // margin-right: 15px

    $(".partCard").css('max-width', itemWidth); // задаем ширину для элемента
} // обвертываем все в событие window.resize() для полной адаптивности
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, медиа запросы

```
.partCard {
    flex-grow: initial;
    width: calc(33.333333% - 15px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .partCard {
        width: calc(50% - 20px);
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
    .partCard {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Под 1920 подгонять не стал, если это решит проблему - распишешь для 1920 медиа запрос

Comment: Сергей, отличная идея, имею на виду чтобы использовать, как хороший вариант. Хочу увидеть разные подходы, после чего отмечу решение.
Рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 0):

```
.selector {
    width: 1080px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: К чему это, объясните?!